# How to avoid assigning a variable in an if

Tags: javascript, refactoring

Given the following snippet:

```
let a;
if (obj === undefined ||
    obj.prop === undefined ||
    (a = await getResultFromLongOperation(obj.prop)) === undefined) {

    // Do things to handle the case where the params were wrong and throw an error

}
console.log(a); // a is not undefined
```

I would like to avoid assigning the value of `a` inside the if.
But I also don't want to make multiple calls to `getResultFromLongOperation` and I don't want to duplicate the "things to handle the case where the params where wrong".

How can I refactor this?

Only solution I found was to refactor as such:

```
function doThingsToHandleTheCaseTheParamsAreWrong() {
    // Do things to handle the case where the params were wrong and throw an error
}

if (obj === undefined ||
    obj.prop === undefined) {
    doThingsToHandleTheCaseTheParamsAreWrong();
}

let a = getResultFromLongOperation(obj.prop);

if (a === undefined) {
    doThingsToHandleTheCaseTheParamsAreWrong();
}

console.log(a); // a is not undefined
```

Is this really better?

Answer (score 0):

Would this construct work in your case:

```
const a = getResultFromLongOperation(obj.prop) || doThingsToHandleTheCaseTheParamsAreWrong();
```

Depending on if `a` can return other falsy values that `undefined`.

```
const tmpA = getResultFromLongOperation(obj.prop);
const a = tmpA !== undefined ? tempA : doThingsToHandleTheCaseTheParamsAreWrong();
```

Comment: It would work, but this just simplifies the solution I gave.